# Helm lint failing

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have created two new templates in the helm chart one for daemonset and the other for a configmap. I tried to do a helm template with an override file and it was successful. However if I do a helm template or helm lint it fails with the below error :

```
[ERROR] templates/: template: splunk-connect-for-kubernetes/charts/splunk-kubernetes-logging/templates/daemonset-containerd.yaml:24:28: executing "splunk-connect-for-kubernetes/charts/splunk-kubernetes-logging/templates/daemonset-containerd.yaml" at <include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configMap-containerd.yaml") .>: error calling include: template: splunk-connect-for-kubernetes/charts/splunk-kubernetes-logging/templates/configMap-containerd.yaml:86:25: executing "splunk-connect-for-kubernetes/charts/splunk-kubernetes-logging/templates/configMap-containerd.yaml" at <.Values.containerd.path>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.path
```

My templates look like this:

Daemonset-containerd.yaml:

```
checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configMap-containerd.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
```

configmap-cri.yaml:

```
pos_file {{ .Values.containerd.path }}/splunk-fluentd-containers.log.pos
```

Can someone please let me know what am I missing out here.

Comment: The `include` line looks suspicious to me, since it seems like you're trying to use a file path as a `{{ define }}` template name, but that's not the error you're getting.  The last line would produce that error if `.Values.containerd` isn't set, either in the subchart's `values.yaml` file or under a correctly-named key in the parent's `values.yaml`.